# Replace html tags

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which looks like that:

`<ul>;<li>java</li>;<li>angular</li>;<li>python</li>;`

I want to replace all html tags.

I tried:

```
    file1 = file1.replaceAll("<TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?)</TAG>", "");
```

However, that gives me back:

`file1 = file1.replaceAll("<TAG\b[^>]*>(.*?)</TAG>", "");`

I really appreciate your reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
file1 = file1.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","");
```

**[REGEX DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/32)**

**On a side note:**

If you can use [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) then it would be a simple trick for you. Something like

```
Jsoup.parse(yourhtml).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <[^>]*>|<[^>\/]\/>
```

Try this.see demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nG1gU7/31

Comment: Why you added this `<[^>\/]\/>`?

Comment: @AvinashRaj realised later its not needed.was trying to be more explicit